# Pi Zero 2 W fails to boot: rcu_sched detected stalls

Tags: boot-issues, crash, pi-zero-w-2

After setting up my Pi with a surveillance-style camera streaming script, it crashed and wouldn't establish its network connection again on restart. So I connected a monitor and got the trace seen in the image below:

[image: boot failure log]

Just to be sure I tried booting again with a fresh Raspian image on the SD card, but to no avail. I wasn't really able to find much regarding this error and Raspberry Pis specifically.

Does this indicate a hardware issue on the board? Are there any steps I can take to narrow down the possible causes?